# Copy completed files larger than 1024M to another directory

Tags: ubuntu

I am using transmission-daemon. These are on torrent completion environment variables supported by transmission-daemon as shown [here](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/wiki/Scripts). In the directory of the completed download, find and copy any files larger than 1024M to another directory.

**This does not work:**

```
find $TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME -type f -size +1024M -exec cp {} /path/to/copies/ \;
```

**This works, but uses the directory for all the completed torrents:**

```
find $TR_TORRENT_DIR -type f -size +1024M -exec cp {} /path/to/copies/ \;
```

**This does work, and copies the parent directory of the completed torrent:**

```
cp -R "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" "/path/to/copies/"
```

*Any help would be greatly appreciated!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" -type f -size +1024M -exec cp {} /path/to/copies/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You want to copy finished torrents to a new location
2. You have a directory ($TR_TORRENT_DIR) where all downloaded torrents go. In the directory, each new torrent has a directory ($TR_TORRENT_NAME) of its own.

Given these assumptions, do

```
find $TR_TORRENT_DIR
```

to search through all folders instead of just one.

Update:
Find files 1G and larger, get path of file, copy entire parent directory of file to destination.

It could look something like below. Can be improved to identify if two or more files are found in sub directories of the same parent directory and only copy it once.

```
find $TR_TORRENT_DIR/ -type f -size +1024M -exec echo {} \; \
| while read filepath
do
    parentdir=$(dirname $filepath)
    cp -a $parentdir /path/to/copies/
done
```

Note that the above may break if the file names contain exotic characters.

Comment: Fair enough - one last update to go

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
cd "$TR_TORRENT_DIR" && cp -R "$TR_TORRENT_NAME" "/path/to/copies/"
```